# What should I do to make the bookmark of the chapters so it is bold?

Tags: formatting

What should I do to make the bookmark of the chapters so it is bold?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\hypersetup
{
    hidelinks, % Remove red boxes
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    pdfauthor={Brian Griffin},
    pdftitle={Wish it, Want it, Do it},
    pdfsubject={Self help},
    pdfkeywords={therapy,healing,chicken soup},
    pdfproducer={Penguin Publishing}
}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}
% Section numbers without prefix or the place for adding a prefix
% "Section".
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Informações}
\blindtext

\section{Conversa informal}

\blindtext

\chapter{Caracterização}
\blindtext

\chapter{Conhecimento criativo}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer obtained by [campa's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398174/what-should-i-do-to-make-the-bookmark-of-the-chapters-so-it-is-bold/398186?noredirect=1#comment990496_398174):

Adding these lines I got the solution:

```
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}
```

**Result**

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}


\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}
% Section numbers without prefix or the place for adding a prefix
% "Section".
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Informações}
\blindtext

\section{Conversa informal}

\blindtext

\chapter{Caracterização}
\blindtext

\chapter{Conhecimento criativo}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you should add that you got that code from the linked answer, didn't you? ;-)